# Advisable number of foreign keys in a single table

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key

I was wondering, keeping performance and optimizations in mind, while designing the database, is there any advisable number of foreign keys you should keep in a single table?

At present, few of my tables are using 4 foreign keys. Would like to know, if number of foreign keys in a single table causes some performance or scalability issues?

I am using MySql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ultimately FKs can affect performance. They will certainly affect insert/delete performance (more lookups), but you have the advantage of guaranteed data integrity.

You should be more than happy to pay a high price for data integrity - a high performance database with inconsistent data is worse than useless - certainly not as much use as a database that's a bit slow but with consistent data.

Yah gets what yah pays for!

Comment: Is there any recommended number of FK in a single table? After which generally it is advised to rework on table designs?

Comment: No. Some reference tables will themselves have no FK constraints. This is almost a religious matter in many ways. My own personal belief is that as a rule of thumb, tables ideally shouldn't have more than 30 fields, and in a scenario like that, more than ~8FKs would seem excessive. Also, having many small tables means that a system can be more flexible. However, it can depend on your own system's requirements - I did once work on a system with > 35,000 (yes, 35 *THOUSAND*) fields but I wouldn't recommend that for sanity!